# How to delete an item of a list from another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, mvvm, swiftui

I made a practice app where the main view is a simple list. When the item of the list is tapped, it presents the detail view. Inside the detail view is a “delete” button that deletes the item.

How can I delete each item form the detail view ?

The main view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< viewModel.items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                        Text(self.viewModel.items[index].title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Practice")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: makeNew) {
                Text("Add")
            })
        }
    }
    
    func makeNew() {
        withAnimation {
            viewModel.items.append(Model(title: "New Item \(viewModel.items.count + 1)"))
        }
    }
}
```

The detail view:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: remove) {
            Text("Delete")
        }
    }
    
    func remove(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            viewModel.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
}
```

And ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Model]()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass item in `DetailView`, like by-index

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(index: index)) {   // << here !!
    Text(self.viewModel.items[index].title)
}
```

so, it is possible to remove by index

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Delete") {
            self.remove(at: IndexSet(integer: self.index))   // << here !!
        }
    }
    
    func remove(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            viewModel.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just one last question. When I replace the code as you say in the detaiView, I got this error: "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads". How can I fix it?