# Forcing a view to unload or don't be displayed when a list has no items

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list that builds up with a `NavigationLink` based on the members of an array. When you click on the list item, the next view loads up to the right displaying the data for that particular item.
When you delete the item, the next one gets displayed. However, when you delete all the items in the list, the last item's data remains left behind on the loaded view. I tried to look at the selected item being nil, or some other form of checking whether something is selected, or the list has at least one item, but I can't figure out how check all this and unload the view.

Here's the code:

```
        @State var selectedNoteId: UUID?

        NavigationView {
            List(data.notes) { note in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: NoteView(note: note),
                    tag: note.id,
                    selection: $selectedNoteId
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(note.text.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines).first!).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text(note.dateText).font(.body).fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: .infinity)

            Text("Select a note or create a new one...")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .navigationTitle("A title")
```

How do I unload `NoteView` and go back to displaying the `Text("Select a note or create a new one...")`

Thanks for the help!

EDITED:

this is how I remove data:

```
func removeNote() {
        if let selection = selectedNoteId,
           let selectionIndex = data.notes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == selection }) {
            //print("DEBUG: delete item: \(selectionIndex)")
            data.notes.remove(at: selectionIndex)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62907153/12299030?

Comment: Thank you but no. My issue is not deleting an item, or doing so from another view, but rather, once the list that holds on the NavigationLinks is empty, because I deleted every item there, unloads the `NoteView` view that is left behind displaying the text from the last (now gone) note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap whole list with `if`

```
NavigationView {
    if !data.notes.isEmpty {
        List(data.notes) { note in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: NoteView(note: note),
                tag: note.id,
                selection: $selectedNoteId
            ) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(note.text.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines).first!).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                    Text(note.dateText).font(.body).fontWeight(.light)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: .infinity)
    } else {
        List(data.notes) { _ in EmptyView() }
    }
    Text("Select a note or create a new one...")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
.listStyle(InsetListStyle())
.navigationTitle("A title")
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        selectedNoteId = data.notes.first?.id
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        data.notes.removeAll()
    }
}
```

When `notes` is empty, content of list isn't being called. Looks like macOS is pretty buggy by not dismissing old navigation link

Comment: Thanks Philip, I tried that already. It you a list of items, and you delete them, the view still is left behind, which is the issue I am trying to solve. This is why I asked how to unload or dismiss a view. The funny thing is that if you click on the list itself, on a blank area, outside any of the NavigationLinks, then the NotesView disappears and the text "Click on..." gets displayed....

Comment: @Aleph sure you've tried this one? I've double checked and after deletion of items `NavigationLink` item disappears with my `if`

Comment: No, It seems different, you are correct. However, the list doesn't show at all when the array is empty, so now the place holder for the list is grayed. Sure, I can set the color to white, or default, but I think this solution is going to come back and create an issue later on... I can't quite place the why. I have a screenshot, but I don't seem to be able to upload it. 
I'm surprised the view is left behind and there isn't a clean up...

Comment: @Aleph I see, this looks like because that background was set by `InsetListStyle`. So a possible solution would be to add an other list in `else` branch.. This code looks even more ugly =) updated my answer, also moved `.listStyle(InsetListStyle())` to it'll affect both lists

Comment: Philip, I haven't tried the code yet, tho I did find a hack. See my answer to the question. It's a little less code.

Comment: @Aleph sure it's up to you, and `hidden` is indeed a cleaner solution, but mine helps you save the background color of your view

Comment: I just tried it and it's neat, busy code, but it's neat, so I'll accept yours as the solution and not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? Im not sure how you are actually removing data when the user deletes it.

```
List(data.notes) { note in
        if data.notes.isEmpty {
            navlink
        } else {
            Text("Select a note or create a new one...")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question, please see above how I remove data. Thank you!

Comment: @Aleph My if else should work, I've removed data the same way you are and used if else to display and updated view based on an array. Let me know once you try it.

Comment: Thank you. It does not work. First you need to add a `not` as in `!if data.notes.isEmpty`, otherwise when you have data it will populate the list with the `Text("Select a note or create a new one...")`. Second, if you look at the code, the text is not displayed as part of the list, but in the location where the new view would be, if there is data to display.
I added the `not (!)` and moved the if around a bit, but when you delete all, it still leaves behind the `NoteView` with the text ofd the last note reviewed. I need to unload `NoteView`, not display any text.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a cleaner way. Add an extension:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func hidden(_ shouldHide: Bool) -> some View {
        switch shouldHide {
        case true: self.hidden()
        case false: self
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `NoteView` call:

```
.hidden(data.notes.isEmpty)
```

And when data is empty the view will go away.
It's an ugly hack, I guess, but somehow the last view is left behind when there are not items in the list, and I can't find any other way to force it to unload.